# iPhone : Is there any Objective C free 3D Engines?

Tags: iphone, open-source, 3d

This might sound like a bit of a silly question but I been looking at OpenGL ES and about to start looking at SIO2 however these both look like like C++ API's and for someone who does not actually know C++ but gets on fine with Objective C, can be very scary.

Is there any actual Objective C iPhone free 3D engines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked in the [Unity games development platform](http://unity3d.com/) yet? It keeps the coding high level and provides you with loads of excellent tools for most aspects of 3D games development. You can also deploy to iPhone / Android / Web simultaneously from a single code base rather than recoding for each platform.

Comment: Is that actually Objective C though?

Comment: You can choose from 3 different languages to write with in Unity. Javascript, C# or Boo (python like). Whichever you choose the end result is compiled down into objective C assembly code for submission ot the App Store.

Comment: Thanks alot, have you used SIO2?

Comment: @Burf2000: No, I've recently started out on iOS 3d development and decided on Unity due to coming from a .Net background. From what I have seen so far it's been pretty good.

Comment: I think I might go and buy the book then, what I want to do is pretty simple but in raw openGL seems alot of work

Comment: Can you use Unity3D for free and deploy it on your device to test? and only pay once you release something